# How to display only the chapters name and not sections and subsections in book class table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, books

How do I remove the section and subsection from the table of contents and just have the chapters?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}    

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Last chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{First section} \lipsum[2-3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4-5]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[6-7]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` to your header.

Comment: In the document preamble, I suppose ...

Comment: I'd say yes, but out of curiosity I made a couple of tries. It works as long as the macro is before `\tableofcontents`, in the preamble as well as in the body of text.

Comment: Can you predict why LaTeX set this as a counter rather than a count? I feel it's strange.